# Pandas - Reading Large CSV directly from URL

Tags: python, pandas, csv, url

I'm new to python/data science in general, trying to understand why the below isn't working:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/fhv_tripdata_2017-06.csv'
trip_df = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv(url, chunksize=1000, nrows=10000):
    trip_df.append(chunk)
trip_df = pd.concat(trip_df, axis='rows')
```

It's returning a MemoryError, but I was under the impression that loading the file in chunks was a workaround for that. I'd prefer not to save the csv to my hard drive, plus I'm not entirely sure if that would help.

My computer's pretty limited, only 4GB of RAM (2.9 usable). I imagine that's a factor here, but if importing the whole file isn't an option, how would I just get part of it, say 5,000 rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
reader = pd.read_csv(url, chunksize=1000, nrows=10000)
df = pd.concat([x for x in reader], ignore_index=True)
```

> how would I just get part of it, say 5,000 rows?

```
df = pd.read_csv(url, nrows=5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```py
with contextlib.closing(urllib.request.urlopen(url=url)) as rd:
    for df in pd.read_csv(rd, chunksize=5, index_col=0):
        print(df)
```

while just

```py
pd.read_csv(url, chunksize=5, index_col=0)
```

crashes with MemoryError.

Answer (score -1):

Just get the 5000 rows in the command line with

```
wget -q -O - https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/fhv_tripdata_2017-06.csv | head -n 5000 > tmp.csv
```

and then proceed with tmp.csv